# Where do I set properties in a VS 2008 Setup project?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I have a WinForms project in Visual Studio 2008, and I've created a Setup project for it. I can build this and it picks up the dependencies and creates the .exe and .msi. But I would like to customize it a little bit, for example by specifying my company name and changing the default 90s-style clip-art logo that appears when the installer executes. But I cannot find anything resembling a properties page where I would do any of this. If I right-click on the Setup project and go to Properties it just gives me options about the output file name, compression of the installer, etc.. Is there some other place I need to go to change things like my company name, the product name, and the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight the project, there will be new icons above the solution explorer.

These buttons are for the file system, registry, etc.  Anything that is effected by the setup.

Comment: Thanks. What a weird design choice.